# I have two unique keys in my table. When using the exception DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX, can I choose which specific (unique) column where the violation occurs?

Tags: javascript, sql, plsql

I'm trying to handle this exception a little more elegantly.

I have two different columns that have unique constraints, emp_id (primary key) and system_id. There are some gaps in the table and entering employee information is currently a manual process.

When raising this exception, is it possible to specify which (or both) column has an existing value?

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
        htp.p('
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function id_exists() {
                    alert("Error: Employee ID or System ID already exists.");
                }

                id_exists();
                window.history.back();
            </script>
        ');
```

Comment: You seem to think that gaps in your primary key column are bad; that's not the case. Gaps are fine (except the very rare case where gapless sequences are required), especially if rows are deleted (e.g. if an employee leaves).

Comment: You question if you can tell which constraint failed, both have failed. @hotfix shows you how to determine which has the error but you cannot know if both fail. Oracle throws the error on the 1st it detects but then doesn't test the other, neither can you determine if it was the second one tested that failed as cannot specify/know the order tested.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the error message has a name of the first or of the second constraint
The names are UPPERcased.

```
begin
....
EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
      if sqlerrm like '%CONSTRAINT_SYSTEM%' then
        ...
      end if;
      if sqlerrm like '%CONTRAINT_EMPNAME%' then
        ...
      end if;
end;
```

here is a smal example: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ccf34b6a9efa47470bc5799eeaa446e0)*